# Travis CI: hide secrets in the output (avoid secrets leak)

Tags: security, travis-ci

Whle travis CI build I execute command like

```
git remote add origin https://${GH_TOKEN}/some/url
git push origin master
```

In the output i got:

```
 Fetch URL:https://<secrte-value>/some/url
```

As it is public repo, build output is aviable  to anybody so this is a secrets leak.

How do I suppose to manage such cases in travis CI? Is there a consistent to avoid secrets leak in the output?

Comment: The question is about filtering log output, not encrypting secrets in the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to manage your issue is described in [Defining encrypted variables in .travis.yml](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Defining-encrypted-variables-in-.travis.yml)

Comment: So i believe it is responsibility of the user not to output secret in the log. And CI itself has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Actually Travis CI does some effort to not shout out your secrets in the log. For example CI will log something like `export GH_TOKEN=[secure]`. But if you would do `echo $GH_TOKEN` then it's your fault.

Comment: I came across this issue several times. The problem are pull requests. What do you do if I change the `.travis.yml` to echo the token and create a pull requests?

Comment: A quick search found that Travis does not expose secrets in pull requests from forks. See [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/pull-requests#Pull-Requests-and-Security-Restrictions).